# How do I manually trigger a printer driver download from software update?

Tags: software-update, printing, driver

When macOS "sees" a printer listed on [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201465), it automatically fetches and installs a printer driver package that will support that printer if it didn't have it already.

For example, if I have a new Mac, and I plug in an HP printer with USB, or see one on Bonjour and try to install it, macOS will install all a driver package for all of the HP printers.

However, I am dealing a lot with network printers that aren't reliable when configured as Bonjour printers, and when I attempt to install these printers by hostname or IP on a new Mac, they will only be recognized as "Generic PostScript Printer", and not trigger the printer driver download. If I already have the drivers installed on a particular Mac, I can do the install by IP as usual, simply select the driver manually, and everything works great. But on a new Mac, these options are missing from the driver list and there does not appear to be an option to reveal the driver options that would normally be provided via a software update package.

Is there any way to proactively tell macOS/softwareupdate "Hey, go out and get the HP/RICOH/whatever drivers because I'm going to need them later whether you think so or not"? I imagine this would also be useful for OS image builders.

Comment: Did you found a solution?